# gnome-terminal: How to close the original tab?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnome, gnome-terminal

Just wrote a script that would open 3 new tabs in a window.

**tab_init.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# options="--hide-menubar --geometry=140x42"
options=""
options_each=()

# tabs
cmds[1]="cd ~/a; clear"
cmds[2]="cd ~/b; clear"
cmds[3]="cd ~/c; clear"

for i in 1 2 3; do
  options_each+=(--tab -e "bash -c '${cmds[i]} ; bash'" )
done

gnome-terminal $options "${options_each[@]}" &

exit 0
```

**Current result:**

After executing the script, there will be 3 more tabs opened in current window, plus the original tab, there would be 4 tabs.

**Desired result:**

But what I want is to open the new tabs in a standalone window, without including any other tab.

**The questions are:**

- How to close the original tab automatically from the script, so that there would be only 3 tabs(*the new ones*) after executing the script?
- Or, can I open the 3 new tabs in a new window, not in the original window, so that it doesn't matter whether I close the original tab.

Comment: Your script is working as expected, it is just opening 3 windows on Centos 7. How are you running the script

Comment: @Inian I guess your default terminal is not `gnome-terminal`, in that case, it will start a new window. But, if the initial terminal is `gnome-terminal`, it will create new tabs in the original window.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of found a way to do this.

First, make soft link of the script into **$PATH**.
e.g link it as `tab_init` somewhere,

Then, define command shortcuts in `~/.bashrc`, to add the extra behavior.

e.g

```
alias tabinit='tab_init; exit' # init tabs, and close original tab,
alias tabinitne='tab_init' # init tabs, and keep the original tab,
```

Now, could use command `tabinit` or `tabinitne` to choose the behavior desired.